# nested array or objects

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing array and objects, though I'm still confusing about making nested objects and arrays.

So i have this type of array and i want to make it nested but i'm having a hard time to do it. I don't know if it is possible.

```js
const data = [
            {
              "Date":"3/24/23",
              "Course":"BASIC ENGLISH",
              "Examiner":"Juan Ponce",
              "Participants":"Nardo Putik",
              "Examiner Approach":"3",
              "Clear explanation of topics discussed":"3",
              "Well organized activity from start to finish":"3"
            },
            {
              "Date":"3/24/23",
              "Course":"BASIC ENGLISH",
              "Examiner":"Juan Ponce",
              "Participants":"Cardo Martinez",
              "Examiner Approach":"3",
              "Clear explanation of topics discussed":"3",
              "Well organized activity from start to finish":"3"
            },
            {
              "Date":"3/24/23",
              "Course":"BASIC ENGLISH",
              "Examiner":"Juan Ponce",
              "Participants":"Ippo Kazuya",
              "Examiner Approach":"3",
              "Clear explanation of topics discussed":"3",
              "Well organized activity from start to finish":"3"
            }
        ]
        
console.log(data);
```

Expected Output :

```
const data = 
  {
    "Date" : "3/24/23",
    "Course" : "BASIC ENGLISH",
    "Examiner" : "Juan Ponce",
    "Details" : 
    [{
      "Participants" : "Ippo Kazuya",
          "Examiner Approach" : "3",
          "Clear explanation of topics discussed" : "3",
          "Well organized activity from start to finish" : "3"
      },
      {
          "Participants" : "Cardo Martinez",
          "Examiner Approach" : "3",
          "Clear explanation of topics discussed" : "3",
          "Well organized activity from start to finish" : "3"
      },
      {
          "Participants" : "Nardo Putik",
          "Examiner Approach": "3",
          "Clear explanation of topics discussed" : "3",
          "Well organized activity from start to finish" : "3"
      }]
  }
```

Comment: Expected output is invalid.

Comment: It's not possible?

Comment: Your expected output is invalid JavaScript.

Comment: are you looking for an object output `{"Date": "3/24/23",...}`

Comment: Your expected output can't have named keys since it is an array. If you make it an object and then put the participant data in an array and give that array a key within the containing parent object, it would be valid. This is good to know if you are new to JavaSCript: `[]` square brackets are for arrays and `{}` curly braces are for objects.

Comment: Alright Now what you can do is iterate over your input data with a loop and fill the Details in your output data. I do not know the exact specifications of this, what I assume is to be a school assignment, but any validation for the Date, Course and Examiner can also be put in that loop.

Comment: I’m little confused. `data = { for var i = 1; ... details.push... }` is this what you mean? This is not for school assignment. I graduated this year.. i do multimedia arts however i want to learn front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). The basic idea is to build up a new output array. For every element in the input array, we'll see if there's already a matching element in the output array. If there is, we just add to its `Details`. If not, we create a new element in the output array.

```
const result = data.reduce((a, { Date, Course, Examiner, ...rest}) => {
  const current = a.find(
    (v) => v.Date === Date && v.Course === Course && v.Examiner === Examiner
  );
  
  if (current) current.Details.push(rest)
  else a.push({ Date, Course, Examiner, Details: [rest] })
  
  return a;
}, []);
```

Note the use of [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to capture the `...rest` of the object properties so they can be easily be added to the `Details` array.

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const data = [{
  "Date": "3/24/23",
  "Course": "BASIC ENGLISH",
  "Examiner": "Juan Ponce",
  "Participants": "Nardo Putik",
  "Examiner Approach": "3",
  "Clear explanation of topics discussed": "3",
  "Well organized activity from start to finish": "3"
}, {
  "Date": "3/24/23",
  "Course": "BASIC ENGLISH",
  "Examiner": "Juan Ponce",
  "Participants": "Cardo Martinez",
  "Examiner Approach": "3",
  "Clear explanation of topics discussed": "3",
  "Well organized activity from start to finish": "3"
}, {
  "Date": "3/24/23",
  "Course": "BASIC ENGLISH",
  "Examiner": "Juan Ponce",
  "Participants": "Ippo Kazuya",
  "Examiner Approach": "3",
  "Clear explanation of topics discussed": "3",
  "Well organized activity from start to finish": "3"
}];

const result = data.reduce((a, { Date, Course, Examiner, ...rest}) => {
  const current = a.find(
    (v) => v.Date === Date && v.Course === Course && v.Examiner === Examiner
  );
  
  if (current) current.Details.push(rest)
  else a.push({ Date, Course, Examiner, Details: [rest] })
  
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: ...rest is this variable? what this code do `if (current) current.Details.push(rest)
  else a.push({ Date, Course, Examiner, Details: [rest] })`?

Comment: `...rest` is the rest of the object properties, i.e. the ones that are not explicitly [desctructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that kind of data restructuring is not suggestable in real time as we are not sure that the values of Date, Course and Examiner fields are same for all the objects in the array.

Suggested approach is to group based on a particular property of objects so that the output can be an object with grouped values as keys.

Comment: Date, Course and Examiner always same.. The only thing that will change is the rating. such as trainer approach etc. and the participants or rater.